# What do I have to installed on PC to use GIT

Tags: git, github

I haven't used Git yet, and want to learn it now - what is necessary to have installed on PC, and what should be removed to not get overwhelmed with stuff? I'm using IntelliJ and already connected my GitHub account with it, so I would prefer to use commands directly from IDE, however I have installed/am able to install following stuff, and would like to know what has to be there, and what's to be removed:

1. GitHub Desktop
2. Git
3. Git bash
4. PuTTy (SSH key creation)

Comment: Github Desktop is essentially a Git GUI specific to using Github as a remote. It can be helpful when you are just getting started, but there is a learning curve and I would try to ween yourself off of it at some point. If you are on Windows, may want to checkout [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/), an open source Git GUI, as a means of visually managing your local git repos. All you need is Git for Windows installed (comes with Git Bash)

Comment: @LightCC As a developer of Gitextensions, I have upvoted your comment 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to download *git* on your PC, if you want to work with IntelliJ and GitHub. You don't need *PuTTy*, *git bash* or *GitHub Desktop*. But you can, if you want! But I guess to download *git bash* too ([www.gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org/)), then this is a git-commandline-program, and there you can run git-commands too.

Download the latest git-version from their own website: [www.git-scm.com/downloads](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Comment: On Windows you have the option to install Git Bash when you install Git from the git-scm downloads page. No need to download it separately!